# Does Hortonworks Data Platform support Ubuntu or not?

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop

I am new to the Hortonworks Data Platform.

Can anyone tell me whether Ubuntu supports Hortonworks Data Platform or not?

Answer (score 0):

It's [not officially supported](http://hortonworks.com/community/forums/topic/ubuntu-support-timeline/). See also [this](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=Horton-works+data+platform+ubuntu).

Comment: While these links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the links for reference. Link-only answers become invalid if any of the linked pages change.

Answer (score 0):

Hortonworks started supporting Ubuntu recently - but they only support HDP 2.0 (not 2.1) for now.

Here's their announcement (from December 3rd, so Stefan's answer was accurate when written)

> Today, we add Ubuntu to the list of options we support for HDP 2.0. We have certified HDP 2.0 on Ubuntu 12.04 Precise, the latest Ubuntu release with Long Term Support.  This is a significant advance as it represents the final mile in terms of Linux coverage.  This along with our version for Windows Server should provide coverage for more than 99% of enterprises in the world.

(It's taken from [this link).](http://hortonworks.com/blog/hortonworks-data-platform-2-0-certified-for-ubuntu-12-04/)